# Clearly explanation of all kinds of memory in Presto

Tags: presto

I'm **SO** confusing about memory-settings in Presto. Please check this out below:

1. `query.max-memory`
2. `query.max-memory-per-node` ([base config](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html))
   [image]
3. `query.max-total-memory` ([release in 0.205](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.205.html))
   [image]
4. `resources.reserved-system-memory` ([admin properties](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/admin/properties.html#general-properties))
   [image]
5. Memory Pools (General Pool & Reserved Pool)
   [image]

That is all I can find out.

Here are my Presto settings:

1. etc/config.properties

> query.max-memory=2.25GB
>   query.max-total-memory=2.25GB
>   query.max-memory-per-node=0.75GB

2. jvm: -Xmx3G -Xms3G

Base on my settings, I found these rules:

1. `query.max-memory-per-node` <= jvm * 0.25
2. General Pool = jvm * 0.4, same as the default value of `resources.reserved-system-memory`
3. Reserved Pool = jvm * 0.3

## Here are my questions:

1. The relationship between all kinds of memory-settings. (like `resources.reserved-system-memory` is General Pool? `query.max-total-memory`=user memory+system memory, what are user memory and system memory?)
2. What General Pool and Reserved Pool use for? How can I change their values?
3. General Pool(40% of jvm), Reserved Pool(30% of jvm), where is the last 30% of jvm? or How Presto assigns my 3GB jvm memory?

Answer (score 2):

```
reserved = query.max-memory-per-node 
system = 40% of heap 
general = heap - system - reserved
```

- [presto-tuning](https://qubole.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/210266303-How-To-Presto-Tuning)
- [about the memory manager](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/hiqvwsmInag)
- [LocalMemoryManager](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/memory/LocalMemoryManager.java)
- [#10512](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/10512)

Comment: From "about the memory manager" link above: The way it works is that the reserved pool gets X GB of memory, where X is the size of the largest query that could be submitted, and the general pool gets all the remaining memory. All submitted queries start in the general pool, but if it becomes full the largest is promoted to the reserved pool. Since the reserved pool has enough memory to run the largest query that query will always complete and therefore the cluster can never deadlock.